# Xslt Adding brackets '( )' for negative values in response while parsing through xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to generate a pdf file from rest response using xslt. Its all working fine but in negative values it is adding bracket surrounding the amount value. Like for the amount= 500$ its working fine but for amount= **-600**$ it's giving (**600$**).

```
<fo:table-cell>                     
    <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="currency:getFormattedCurrency(amount/currency/text(), amount/amount/text())" />
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

here is my **getFormattedCurrency()**

```
NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currencyLocale);
        currencyFormatter.setCurrency(currency);
        return currencyFormatter.format(amount);
```

i have also tried other way of using **contain()** of xslt so that i can identify if its having negative sign string and i can treat those negative value differently and positive values differently. like this--

```
<fo:table-cell>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(string(availableAmount), '-')">
                <xsl:value-of select="-1*(currency:getFormattedCurrency(availableAmount/currency/text(), availableAmount/amount/text()))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="currency:getFormattedCurrency(availableAmount/currency/text(), availableAmount/amount/text())" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>                           
    </fo:block>                     
</fo:table-cell>
```

Looking for suggestions/solutions to achieve the target result by modifying xsl file preferably.[attached 
 is the image of what i am getting for negative values with bracket and positive values correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6g6M.png) and here is the pic what is want actually. [image: correct required values]

Happy to accept other way of solving this problem. :)

Comment: Where is the define the functio in your xsl file `currency:getFormattedCurrency` in that function there might be declaration to checking value as negative and surround in `()`.

Comment: Have you thought about using the format-number XSLT instruction instead?  It should do what you want.

Comment: @amrendra function definition is already provided above but I can't change function definition as it's from framework of my company which can't be changed.

Comment: @bluewood66 I can't change anything in my Java class as it's part of my company framework. If your answer is in respect of xsl changes only. Please provide any example for this so that I can start exploring about that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different countries have different currency format so when it comes to USA it represents negative amount in bracket () and India represents negative amount with minus sign. XSL automatically format this notation according to country currency. Hence this is not actually any issue it's just way of representation of different currency format.

Answer (score 0):

So, here you are replacing the choose and the java with the format-number.  And, creating the format on the fly.  It's a bit of a complication.  See if it's something you want.

```
<fo:table-cell>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(availableAmount/amount, concat('#,###', availableAmount/currency, ';', '-#,###', availableAmount/currency))" />
  </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```